# Java ( Reading userinput.equalsIgnoreCase() in Arraylist)

Tags: java

I was writing a list of menu for my product and wanted to use a simple String (and wanted to use .equalsIgnoreCase() so that it would ignore whatever text casing it is) and compare it in ArrayList pre-coded (as i was adding a new product)  using .contain(); however it still depends on text casing and I couldn't find answers. Hoping that someone would help me :).

```
static void AddProductCode() {
    boolean print = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(productcode.get(i)+"     " +product.get(i)+"        "+ productprice.get(i));
        }
  
    System.out.print("PRODUCT CODE : ");
    code = scan.next();
    code.equalsIgnoreCase(code);
    boolean check = productcode.contains(code);
   
    if(check == true){  
            System.out.println("CODE IS UNAVAILABLE");
            AddProductCode();
        
    }
    
    else {
            AddProduct2nd();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you believe the line `code.equalsIgnoreCase(code);` does?

Comment: ignore case of the user input. I itried puting it inside of If statement but it doesnt work

Comment: I wanted to use equalsIgnoreCase() so that whatever I input on the terminal when i run the code. If it flagged that there was a similar text It would not accept it .

Answer (score 0):

The `List#contains(Object)` compares the given object with each element of the list using the equals() method. The `String#equals()` method checks equality by taking the case into consideration.

So, for that you can manually implement the logic.

Replace the `boolean check = productcode.contains(code);` with

```
boolean check = false;
for (String e: productcode) {
    if (e.equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
        check = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, `check` will be true if `code` is present in `productcode` irrespective of the case. If `check` is false this means that `code` is not present in `productcode`

Comment: willl try this. be back for after i boot up